# S3 Bucket Endpoint for Static Website Hosting

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've hosted a static website on S3 bucket in *US East (N. Virginia)* region. The endpoint is something like this

http:// ***BucketName*** .s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com

This region has also a valid endpoint name

s3.amazonaws.com

I want change mine to something like
http://s3.amazonaws.com/ **BucketName** /

Is there a way I can do so?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Amazon S3 Url rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570890/amazon-s3-url-rewrite)

Comment: @artem-arkhipov Many thanks.The reference is probably using my own domain. But in my case, I just wanted to alter endpoint from one to another. Not to use my own domain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can point to an Amazon S3 bucket using the `s3.amazonaws.com/bucketname` method, however:

- This does not enable the **Static Website Hosting** features (such as using default `index` and `error` pages)
- **It is being deprecated**. See: [Amazon S3 Path Deprecation Plan – The Rest of the Story | AWS News Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-path-deprecation-plan-the-rest-of-the-story/)

Comment: Many Thanks.

**You can point to an Amazon S3... method**

As a newbie to S3,I don't know how to? 

**1.** And I already have seen someone using this path for their Static Website Hosting _(Reference Url is not appropriate to post here)_ But Yes, it's possible.

**2** Thanks, But I think there is still enough time for me.

Comment: The URL is simply `s3.amazonaws.com/bucketname/objectname`. This actually leads to a page redirect to the correct region, so you could instead use something like `s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/bucketname/objectname` to go directly.

Comment: Thank You very much. I just put **index.html** as **objectname** and now its working.